# Not able to upload file using curl command with other json parameter in lumen php project api

Tags: php, curl, file-upload, lumen

I want to call my upload csv api using curl command but no able to upload file on that which gives me error.
Command I am using as follow:

```
 curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://api.staging.mailzap.com/api/v1/api-key/upload-csv -d '{"apiKey":"Srkk8RL8xETAeJ0lTm85","email_csv":'@\"C:/Users/viral.champanery/Desktop/publicapi/test.txt\"',"team_id":282}'
```

following option also not working

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data;application/json;application/csv;" https://api.staging.mailzap.com/api/v1/api-key/upload-csv -d '{"apiKey":"Srkk8RL8xETAeJ0lTm85","email_csv":"C:/Users/viral.champanery/Desktop/publicapi/test.txt","team_id":282}'
```

also not working following

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:multipart/form-data;application/json;application/csv;" https://api.staging.mailzap.com/api/v1/api-key/upload-csv -d '{"apiKey":"Srkk8RL8xETAeJ0lTm85","team_id":282}' -F "email_csv=@/C/Users/viral.champanery/Desktop/publicapi/test.csv"
email_csv=@/C/Users/viral.champanery/Desktop/publicapi/test.csv"
```

help me to upload file with json other parameter in api using curl command

Comment: "_Not able to upload file_" meaning what exactly? Any errors? Logfile? Uploading the wrong .csv? Does your API work at all?

Comment: @kerbholz,Yes my api working with postman and integrated with UI, but I am not able to send file to server using curl call with api.with json other api working file using curl..